# t- test for non normally distributed sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, normal-distribution, t-test, normalization

I am doing a statistical test (analysis) for the following case:
As part of a product aimed at improving the quality and speed of code writing for developers,
we have implemented a new feature that should make code review faster.

- Checking the time for code reviews in these groups :

1. Before the implementation date of the feature
2. After the implementation date of the feature

- Each group represents a vector of times in minutes
- The 2 samples distribution is unKnown (abnormal)
  I have tried several transformations to bring about a normal distribution, but without success.
  So I used U-test
- I use Python to write
  My question is:

What **statistical significance test** should I use when I have an **abnormal distribution** with **time data** and not numerical data?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean by time data instead of numerical data? Do you mean that your Python code stores a datetime object instead of a raw number?

Comment: Specifically, I measure time data for both groups: the duration of an action (in minutes).
* The data type is less important
What statistical significance test should I use? This is the focus of the question. Thanks

Comment: You mention the Mann–Whitney–Wilcoxon rank sum test (U-test). It should work well for your data, as it doesn't assume the variables are normally distributed. So you have (at least) two options: U-test and permutation test. As an side: duration (measured in minutes, hours, etc) is a numeric variable, though obviously non-normal as duration is nonnegative and very often right skewed.

Answer (score 4):

For testing a difference between the means of both groups, a t-test (aka "Welch test" to make clear that no assumption of equal variances is made) can even be used when the data of both groups are not normally distributed: for a sufficient number of samples, the mean value is approximately normally distributed due to the Central Limit Theorem.

A non-parametric alternative is a permutation test: for a number (say $K=10000$) of times, permute the group labels in the data and compute the difference between the group means. The p-value is the proportion of permutations for which the difference is greater than the actually observed difference.

The usual caveat applies: statistical significance does not mean importance, and you should therefore also check whether the difference is large enough to be of practical relevance.